# How to get last objects from an array of the identical objects?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

How can I get the last object from an array of identical objects. I attached the code. I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Input

```
[
      {name:'Sam', count:3},
      {name:'Sam', count:5},
      {name:'Sam', count:8},
      {name:'Jill', count:7},
      {name:'Jill', count:6},
    ]
```

Output

```
 [
      {name:'Sam', count:8},
      {name:'Jill', count:6},
 ]
```

Comment: Do you want to get the last record of each item by name?

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+remove+duplicate+objects+by+property,+get+only+last) of [How to get the last occurrence of the duplicated array in Javascript](/q/56437311/4642212). Basically `const result = Array.from(yourArray.reduce((result, object) => { result.set(object.name, object); return result; }, new Map()).values());`. See the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: @lucumt yes, each item by name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to do it, each time we check if the name exists or not,if it exists then remove the exists one and put the new one into the result array

---

Update: Based on @Simon's comment,I update my answer with more simple code

```js
let data = [
      {name:'Sam', count:3},
      {name:'Sam', count:5},
      {name:'Sam', count:8},
      {name:'Jill', count:7},
      {name:'Jill', count:6},
    ]
    
let result = Object.values(data.reduce((a,c) => {
   a[c.name] = c
   return a
},{}))    
console.log(result)
```